# a problem on finding acceleration by differentiation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, differentiation

The displacement of particle along the $x$ and $y$ axis is
\begin{cases}
x(t)=\omega t-\sin\omega t\\
y(u)=1-\cos\omega t
\end{cases}
Upon differentiation, the velocity is
\begin{cases}
v_x(t)=\omega\left(1-\cos\omega t\right)\\
v_y(t)=\omega\sin\omega t
\end{cases}
so 
$$v =\sqrt{v_x^2+ v_y^2} = 2w \sin (wt /2)$$

My problem is if I find the magnitude of acceleration by differentiation of components $v_x$ and $v_y$  followed by their sum, I get a constant acceleration $w^2$ but if I directly differentiate $v$ I got variable acceleration $w^2 \cos (wt/2)$.
I don't understand why. How are the two methods different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I square $v_x$ and $v_y$, I get
\begin{align}
v(t)&=\sqrt{\left(\omega-\omega\cos\omega t\right)^2+\omega\sin^2\omega t}\\
&=\left[\omega^2+\omega^2\cos^2\omega t-2\omega^2\cos\omega t +\omega\sin^2\omega t\right]^{1/2}\\
&=\omega\sqrt{2-2\cos\omega t}
\end{align}
which, due to the square root term, is slightly different than what you have. Differentiating this returns
$$
\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{\omega^2\sin\omega t}{\sqrt{2-2\cos\omega t}}
$$
which is also radically different than $a(t)=\sqrt{a_x(t)^2+a_y(t)^2}$ and your answer of $dv/dt$. The real answer is indeed the $\omega^2$ you've found via the components.

The reason the two methods do **not** align is because the particle's motion is along a *curve*. That is to say, your *direction* is changing. Note that the relationship for the magnitude is
$$
\lvert a\rvert=\left\lvert\frac{dv}{dt}\right\rvert\neq\frac{d|v|}{dt}
$$
You *must* treat the acceleration as a vector, take the *components* derivative, and then find the magnitude afterwards.